# Retrieve first sentence of article stored in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I need to display the first sentence (up to the first full stop) of each article in my database, using MySQL.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('Here is my text. Hope this works!', '.', 1);
```

If there's no dot in your text, it will return the whole text.

Comment: What if there's no dot in that field?

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive approach to your problem. However, it relies on every full stop having a space immediately afterwards.

```
select substr(article, 0, instr(article, '. ')) from articles_table;
```

If you need it to be more reliable, then you would probably need a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to that directly from your SQL query.

To do that, you can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

You will probably need to combine it with `REPLACE` to take in consideration exclamation (!) and question (?) marks.

Comment: Please remove duplicate answers when you realize the answer's already there. Even when it wasn't there when you started, they show up when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Clinton's answer is great, just make sure you tack that end-of-sentence period back onto the string:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Here is my text. Hope this works!', '.', 1), '.');
```

Answer (score -1):

You should search for any delimiters (. ? !) with `strpos()` and find the position of the first occurence. After that:

```
$first_sentence = substr($your_sentence, 0, $first_occurance+1);
```

Edit: you should take into precaution when there is no delimiter, by setting a default max length to show:

```
$max_length = 40;
$stop = $first_occurance > $max_length ? $max_length : $first_occurance + 1;
$first_sentence = substr($your_sentence, 0, $stop);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

@klausbyskov sure, if you want the logic to reside there. It's not a heavy calculation to do on the php-side though.

Comment: *"Why the downvote?"* Probably because the OP asked a MySQL question, and you answered with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

If you're sure all the sentences stop with a dot ('.') you can probably achieve that pretty easily with regular expressions.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

You should google "regular expression 'your language'". I think pretty much every high level language has regular expression support.